# call to execve has too few arguments, but should be receiving full amount

Tags: c

I receive an error when I make the call to execve, I am confused on why when I pass a char array into it, it does not accept my full input and considered it too few arguments. This program is meant to take file names as an input, and then sort them into a directory called SORTED. I know that execve requires 3 arguments, but am I wrong in the calling?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ){

    //arguments
    int i, status, finish = 1;
    pid_t *childPID;
    char buffer[256];

    //checks to make sure there is arguments 
    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        sprintf( buffer, "No arguments were given.\n" );
        write( 2, buffer, strlen( buffer ) );
        return (-1);
    }

    //uses mkdir to check if directory is there
    //if it is not, makes it with 0777 permissions 
    //if it exists, it prints out error message saying that
    //any other error happens, it uses perror to print out the error
    if(mkdir( "./SORTED", S_IRWXU ) == 0) {
        sprintf( buffer, "Creating SORTED folder with 0700 Permissions.\n" );
        write( 1, buffer, strlen( buffer ) );    
    }
    else if (errno == EEXIST) {
        sprintf( buffer, "SORTED folder already exists.\n" );
        write( 2, buffer, strlen( buffer ) );
    }
        else
            perror( "mkdir" );


    childPID = (pid_t*)malloc(sizeof(pid_t)*(argc));
    //for each argument, forks a new child from parent
    //calls execve, prints error if there is one
    //and then sleeps for 20 seconds before exiting
    for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
        char output[256];
        sprintf( output, "SORTED/%s", argv[i] );
        char *newARGV[] = { "sort", "-o", output, argv[i], NULL };
        if ( childPID[i] = fork() == 0 ) {
            execve( "/usr/bin/sort", newARGV);
            perror( "execve" );
            exit( 0 );
        }    
    }

    //Goes through each argument, waits on the child PID
    //Prints if the sort was successful, and if not, prints error code
    for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
        waitpid( childPID[i], &status, 0 );
        if ( status == 0 )
           sprintf( buffer, "%s : success (%d)\n", argv[i], status );
        else {
            finish = 0;
            sprintf( buffer, "%s : fail (%d)\n", argv[i], status );

        }
        write( 1, buffer, strlen( buffer ) );
    }

    //Prints the all done if there was no errors
    //informs you if there were errors
    if ( finish == 1 ) 
        sprintf( buffer, "All Done.\n" );
    else
        sprintf( buffer, "All Done. Error was encountered.\n" );
    write( 1, buffer, strlen( buffer ) );

    free(childPID);
    return 0;   
}
```

The full error is:

```
error: too few arguments to function ‘execve’
       execve( "/usr/bin/sort", newARGV);
```

Comment: `execve` [requires 3 arguments](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html). You aren't providing 3.

Comment: ^^^^ If the error message could be any clearer, I'm pressed to see how.

Comment: You're confusing the arguments to the program you are launching with the arguments to the *function*  (`execve`) you're using to run the program you are launching. The former are supplied in the array; the latter are supplied in your *code* at the call site. It is the latter where you are not living up to the requirements of the function you're calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `execve` function expects three arguments but you're passing two arguments.  Hence the error message.

You seem to be under the impression that passing an array to a function means that each element of the array becomes an argument to the function, but that is not the case.

The function is declared as follows:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

The first argument is the command to run, the second is an array of arguments, and the third is an array of environment variables.  If you're not interested in passing environment variables, use `execv` instead which doesn't have the third argument.

Comment: That fixed the issue, I didnt even realize I had an extra 'e' at the end. Thank you